# JMeter 2.10 Random Variable that gets data from string

Tags: variables, random, jmeter

I have 1st thread group that GETs some id's and writes it to the variable. 
This var has view like that "654564546,564564,56454,56456454,21231321,8972341,65423187".
I need to pick up randomly one of the id and put it to the another variable.
In jmeter 2.07 I used this code:

```
import java.util.Random;

String[] erroridcox = (vars.get("erroridcox")).split(",");

int id1 = new Random().nextInt(erroridcox.length);
String randerror = (erroridcox[id1]);

vars.put("rnd_erroridcox", randerror);
```

But in Jmeter 2.10 this code doesn't work. 
Jmeter log says:

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Random;  String[] erroridcox = (vars.get("erroridcox")).split( . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
```

Comment: Found a problem. Issue is caused that my erroridcox string has view like that: 'code' ["45654","564564","908098"] 'code'. Could you please halp me to escape symbols [ ] " .

Comment: I have read about trim function, but I don't know how to use it in BeanShell pre-processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, the only possible failure point is your `erroridcox` variable not being set.

Add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to double-check `erroridcox` and `rnd_erroridcox`variable values.

Also you can put `debug();` function at the beginning of your script and look into STDOUT to observe its flow - it will provide sufficient information to figure out the cause.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more debugging techniques explained.

Answer (score 0):

Beanshell error message aren't super informative and rarely provide useful information about the actual issue. Use a try catch block to get more information.

```
try {
   //Place your script here
}
catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("OMG Beanshell ERROR::", e);
}
```

see jmeter.log for logged error.